# is char_t an existing global typedef in VS?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I've the following

```
namespace settings{
  #if defined(WIN32) && !defined(UNIX)
  typedef wchar_t char_t;
  #elif defined(UNIX) && !defined(WIN32)
  typedef char char_t;
  #else
  typedef char char_t;
  #endif
  typedef std::basic_string<char_t> string_t;
  typedef std::basic_ostream<char_t> stream_t;
}
```

I kept it such that I can change the whole application taking chat to wchar. It works in Linux but when I tried to compile the same in VS 2010 It is giving me

> error C2371: 'settings::char_t' : redefinition; different basic types
>   see declaration of 'settings::char_t'

all my code uses `settings::char_t` and `settings::string_t` etc .. Now Do I need to change all my code ? or there is some easier way out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if it were a global, your typedef is enclosed in `namespace setting` and you would get more information about this. Are you sure the file isn't being targetted twice in the project?

Comment: what do you mean by being targetted twice ? double inclusion is not possible as headers have the `ifndef/def` defines

Comment: Oh! yes. I was over sure. IDE didn't create the defines to protect double inclusion. Thanks